# Eons class get called in android?

Tags: android, linux

There is an internal API class **Eons** in android. Can anyone knows when this class get called

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know what is Eons -

> Eons is short for "Enhanced Operator Name String". Seems related to
>   Roaming. Just seen in the settings that I had the "connect to data
>   services while roaming" check activated.

if you want to see when it is called - what you can do is to download the [AOSP](http://source.android.com/), build it, run it, and place breakpoints in [Eons class](https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/ag-gb-dsds-7227/repository/revisions/3c2d241d96579e6a54af1a86213a3babf5061148/entry/frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/gsm/Eons.java)

Comment: I Want do is when I am in roaming I want to latch to a particular operator. For example  there are 2 operator A and B. I always want to latch to operator A not to B. will this class help me in this?? how can i get list of available networks and latch to particular  network??

Comment: I think getEonsForAvailableNetworks is what you are looking for

Comment: Do you have any jar which provide this method as i am not able get net Please help!!!

Comment: Can you please provide any example to implement this.It will be very helpful